# subpath url alias does not seem to fire 404

Tags: path-aliases, uri

I'm using subpath_alias, so /node/4/video alias is available too.
But now, and I'm not sure subpath_alias is involved, /node/4/foo does not fire 404 and instead it shows the page as if it was /node/4.

Any clue ?
TIA, Tom